# Updating every single block (4bits) with different value in 64 bit unsigned variable?

Tags: c

I have a variable `unsigned __int64 text=0x0;` and I need to and update each 4 bits with different values.

text = b64b63...b3b2b1b0
I have a loop and inside of the loop must be like this :

```
for(i=0;i<16;i++)
 {
     b3b2b1b0=a[0]
     b7b6b5b4=a[1]
     b11b10b9b8=a[2]
     ..
     .. 
     ..
 }
```

I tried this one but didn't work

```
unsigned __int64 temp=0x0;
unsigned __int64 index=0x0;
for(i=0;i<16;i++)
 {
    index = (text>>(i*4))&0x0F;
    temp = a[index];
    text = text | temp<<(i*4);
 }
```

thank you so much

Comment: So you have a 64-bit variable initialized to zero, but it's not really clear what the result should be. *Where* do you get each [nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble)? For some (possible) input, what should the result be? Why do you need a loop if you get all the bits for the variable inside the loop?

Comment: a[] has 16 elements and each element should be assign to 4 bits in text variable respectively first element goes first lowest 4 bits second goes second lowest 4 bits.I just explained in the question,which part is not clear for you ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use bitshifting and bitwise-OR to do this.  Assuming the `a[n]` values are all between 0 and 15 and also `unsigned __int64`s:

```
unsigned __int64 text=0x0;

text = a[0] |
       a[1] << 4 |
       a[2] << 8 |
       etc....;
```

If you don't trust the `a[n]` values, use `(a[n] & 0xF)` to clear all but the four least significant bits before shifting.  If `a[n]` is not an `unsigned __int64`, cast it before shifting.

Answer (score 1):

You could use bit fields:

```
typedef struct {
    int n0 : 4;
    int n1 : 4;
    int n2 : 4;
    int n3 : 4;
    int n4 : 4;
    int n5 : 4;
    int n6 : 4;
    int n7 : 4;
    int n8 : 4;
    int n9 : 4;
    int n10 : 4;
    int n11 : 4;
    int n12 : 4;
    int n13 : 4;
    int n14 : 4;
    int n15 : 4;
} S64;

typedef union {
    uint64_t i;
    S64 b;
} U64;
```

Note: you may need to pay attention to to the endianness of your target platform(s), if you require a specific ordering of the 4 bit fields within the 64 bit value.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but it looks like it does only works for big endian and most of current computer use little endian?

Comment: @Holt: yes, I think endianness is a potential issue whatever solution you come up with for this - for cross-platform compatibility you would probably need to handle endianness explicitly - for a single platform then you just code it for the target endianness.

Comment: @Holt I'd say it depends on how one initializes the bit-field structure. :)

Comment: @PaulR bitshifts are endianness agnostic

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin: true, but you may still need to pay attention to the ordering of the 4 bit fields, e.g. if you are going to be storing this data in a platform-agnostic way, or sending it over a network.

Answer (score 1):

If you *must* use a loop, you can do something like

```
uint64_t text = 0;
for (int i = 15; i >= 0; --i)
{
    text <<= 4;
    text |= a[i] & 0x0f;  // Masking in case a[i] have more than the lowest four bits set
}
```

Comment: Don't we lose the text bits ? also you are masking a[15] with lowest 4 bits why ? it should be a[0]&0x0f

Comment: @erfgds Notice that bitwise shift of `text` in the loop? Try it out while running in a debugger, step through the code line by line and watch the variables change.

Comment: Yeah I tried and it is not correct , i tested it with correct outputs sorry

Comment: @erfgds Made a slight update, it should work correctly now ([see e.g. this (very simple) example](http://ideone.com/0dWjme)).

Comment: @erfgds Then you need to tell us what "input" you have, and what the result should be. And how does your current work or not work? What output do you get? What output did you expect? And can you perhaps create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Please edit your question to include all details or it will be hard or even impossible to actually help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. I have tried to copy 0x01, 0x02....0x0f into 16 different nibbles. The code extracts the values and shifts them appropriately combined with the OR operation.

```
#define NIBBLES   16      /* 64-bit has 16 nibbles */
#define MASK      0x0FLLU  


int main()
{
    unsigned int val[NIBBLES] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
                                 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f};

    long long unsigned int num = 0, tmp;
    int i, shift = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < NIBBLES; i++) { 
        tmp = (val[i] & MASK) << shift;
        num = num | tmp;
        shift = shift + 4;
    }
    printf ("0x%llx\n", num);

}
```

Output: 0xfedcba9876543210